# Is it possible to set a taxonomy menu programmatically?

Tags: 7, routes, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to create set a taxonomy menu location programmatically? Ie, I have taxonomy_menu installed, have the taxonomy configured and the menu set up, and want to set the taxonomy menu location for the menu with php, something like:

```
taxonomy_menu_set_menu_location($menu, $menu_location)
```

which would then run the same function in the taxonomy_menu_vocab_submit() handler.

is there something existing, or should I DIY?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It's not clear if you want to know if it is possible with the module you installed, or if you want to know if there is a module that allows that.

Comment: Thanks kiamlaluno - either would be great, but it looks like the module itself doesn't offer this functionality.